# Fold numa arvore binária em haskell

Tags: árvore-binária, haskell

Olá, estou tentando definir a função foldTree que recebe uma função e uma árvore polimórfica binária como parâmetros e retorna o valor resultante de acumular a aplicação dessa função por todos os nós da árvore. Depois somar todos os nós da árvore usando essa função foldTree e usando apenas recursão

Eu estou definindo minha árvore como:

```
data Tree a = Nulo 
            | No a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

Preenchendo a árvore

```
tree1 :: Tree Int
tree1 = No 1 Nulo (No 2 Nulo(No 3 Nulo Nulo))
```

Função foldTree

```
foldTree :: (b -> b -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f Nulo = 0
foldTree f (No a e d) = f (foldTree f e)(foldTree f d)
```

E por último as funções somaTree e somaTree com folding

```
somaTree :: Tree a -> Int
somaTree Nulo = 0
somaTree (No a e d) = 

somaTreeFold :: Tree a -> Int
```

Comment: Tente mostrar o que você já vez. O que você já tentou? Conseguiu compilar? Se sim, o resultado foi o esperado? Se não, que tipo de erro você teve?

Comment: A dúvida era na aplicação da função foldTree, não estava compilando, tinha error de casamento de padrões. A solução que encontrei foi transformar a árvore numa lista e aplicar fold na lista, quanto aplicar fold diretamenta na árvore não consegui.

Comment: Você deveria mostrar como implementou para que alguém pudesse dizer onde está o erro ou tentar ajudá-lo a melhorar.